# Recursively finding palindromes

Tags: recursion, common-lisp

So I'm trying to recursively find palindromes, I've generated a huge nested list that looks like so `'((n n n)(n n n)(n n n))` Where n is numbers ofc using the function:

```
(defun double-lst (lst1 lst2)
  (mapcar #'(lambda (n)
               (multiply-lst n lst2))
          lst1))
```

the list is absolutely huge. I'm trying to write a recursive function that searches the car and cdr of my list using the template:

```
    (DEFUN func (X)
     (COND (end-test-1 end-value-1)
           (end-test-2 end-value-2)
           (T (combiner (func (CAR X))
                        (func (CDR X))))))
```

But I can't seem to get my version or anything I've tried to work.
I've tried stuff along the lines of this:

```
(defun find-palindrome (lst)
  (cond ((equal lst (reverse lst)) lst)
        (t (or (find-palindrome (car lst))
               (find-palindrome (cdr lst))))))
```

The function find-palindrome is passed (reverse lst) so that it works from the highest values first returning the first palindrome, but I don't know how to get the recursive function to do its stuff.
I'd really appreciate an in depth explanation on how to write car/cdr recursion. Thanks :)
EDIT: 
my crappy find-palindrome returns this:

```
    CL-USER> (find-palindrome '((1 2 3 4)(13 4 51 3) (1 2 4 9009)))
; Evaluation aborted on #<TYPE-ERROR expected-type: SEQUENCE datum: 1>.
```

I'd expect it to return (9009).

Comment: Can you provide some examples of calling `find-palindrome` and what you would expect it to return?

Comment: All done. I was supposed to do it, but I forgot.

Comment: Lisp shows a backtrace. Did you look at it? Have tried to trace the function calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template does not apply to this problem; `(car lst)` isn't necessarily a list, but the argument to `find-palindrome` is expected to be.  Or at least you need to be sure `(car lst)` is a list before passing it to `find-palindrome`.

Similarly, you seem to want to see if the digits of a number are a palindrome; `reverse` is meant to reverse the elements of a list, not the digits of a number.

Comment: Yeah, I think I screwed that up :O Is there a way to break a number up into individual atoms so I can reverse that?

Comment: @Floofk Try `(map 'list #'digit-char-p (princ-to-string n))`. It converts `n` to a string, and then for each character in the string calls `digit-char-p` on it and returns a list of the results. `digit-char-p` is a function that takes a character and if it is a digit, returns the numerical value for that digit.

Comment: @malisper Why bother mapping it? You could just compare the strings: `(let ((n-str (princ-to-string n))) (string= n-str (reverse n-str))))`